# Is the infinity gauntlet less powerful than each individual stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, avengers-infinity-war

In *Infinity War* (have NOT seen it) Thanos is more than likely to get ALL the Infinity Stones (maybe not all at once) but still ALL of them. Anyway. Could you say that it is much worse than the rest of them individually.

-The Power Stone literally can destroy a planet by touching the ground. Something Thanos won’t likely do in *Infinity War*.

-The Time Stone can freeze time. Something Thanos won’t likely do in *Infinity War*.

-The Mind Stone can make the user intangible. Something Thanos won’t likely do in *Infinity War*.

-The Aether can undo the universe (combined with the Space Stone to create portals). And guess what??? It’s something Thanos won’t likely do in *Infinity War*.

-The Soul Stone can-Don’t tell me. But probably something OP that Thanos won’t likely do in *Infinity War*.

-The Space Stone can create energy- Not that interesting really. Hmmm...

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy, and thanks for posting. Do you not want spoilers in your answers? That could be very hard.

Comment: No thanks. Although I know who dies. I know. Try relating it to the comics which I have not read nor care to read

Comment: Unfortunately, the comics alone won’t provide an effective answer to the movies (which are what you seem to be asking about).

Comment: It’s just that your question is wholly about the movies. If you want an answer based on the comics, why not ask about the comics?

Comment: You seem adamant to give the answer adamant. i'll tell you what. Give me the answer in answer form and I will tick it without reading it. I will then watch infinity war in later days to come back and read it

Comment: We *do* have spoiler markup, which I would have employed anyway for such a popular and new film.

Comment: Ok... Sure, use that.

Comment: Energy Stone? The 6 infinity stones in the MCU are space, time, reality, soul, mind and power...is there another stone we don't know about?

Comment: @geewhiz - They mean Space. I’ll edit it soon.

Comment: done that for you already

Comment: Welcome to the site! While it is good to accept correct answers, "I'll tick it without reading it" goes contrary to the purpose of the SE model. I realize you are new to the site, so I would suggest reading the [help section](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) on [how to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as ]taking the tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Just saying. First of all, I read it without the spoiler bits and even I see that they have explained the evidence in their spoilers so I know the answer is correct. And second of all, that sounds a bit cheesy. No offence intended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, but.

We aren’t given much reason to believe that the stones are less powerful together.

- Once Thanos obtains the Power Stone, he doesn’t use it to destroy a planet. However, he *does* use it in concert with the other stones for something much more impressive. See below.

  > He also uses it to destroy the massive Asgardian ship, and probably Knowhere.

  We aren’t given any reason to think he *couldn’t* destroy a planet with it, though. It just never comes up.

  As far as why

  > The energy output of the Power Stone against individual characters seems lower.

  Keep in mind that it could be working at a maximum power *density*. Enough to kill every ordinary person on a planet if they were exposed to it, but not necessarily capable of readily killing, well….
- What Thanos does with the Time Stone once he gets it isn’t much less impressive than what Doctor Strange uses it for:

  > He uses it to reverse time, restoring Vision and the Mind Stone itself from destruction. Roughly similar to what Strange did with Dormammu.
- Intangibility is *not* the main power of the Mind Stone. That’s mind control, as in what Loki did.

  And since

  > that was the last stone Thanos obtained,

  it’s not shocking that we don’t see much of its powers.
- The Aether could undo the universe, but it’s important to distinguish between what a stone does by itself, and what its wielder is capable of. See below. Further, Thanos doesn’t destroy the universe, but, well….

  In fact, Thanos uses the Reality Stone for various things that Malekith seemed incapable of. Arguably, he actually possesses a better understanding of it.
- We don’t really know what the Soul Stone does in the MCU yet.
- Energy creation is very much a side effect of the Space Stone. Its main power is to warp space, creating portals.

  > Thanos does a lot of this in *Infinity War*

Finally, once Thanos obtains all the Infinity Stones, he does something that no Stone individually, whether in the hands of a sentient being or not, has been able to do:

> He kills half of all sentient beings everywhere in the universe.

That said, it’s clear that the capabilities of the Stones are limited by their wielders. No one can wield their full powers. Most creatures need special items (e.g. the Infinity Gauntlet) to even try. Thanos may be very strong, but we don’t know how easy it is for him to wield even one, let alone several simultaneously.

Also, he’s not one for cleverness and planning (in the MCU, anyway). Yes, he was able to manipulate the events so the Infinity Stones came to light, so he’s not unintelligent, but he doesn’t seem to like this much. He seems to prefer brute force. So he doesn’t seem to bother being very clever with the Stones. Once he has one, he just smashes through toward his goal.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the bit about cleverness/planning. As you pointed out, he manipulated the MCU to find the Infinity Stones over the course of decades (since WW2) also, there was that bit of strategery with the Reality Stone knowing what he needed to complete the collection. I think he just "prefers" brute force against the heroes because it's laughable to think a human could stand up to him in a fist fight

Comment: @gee - That's basically what I'm saying. He can be clever when he wants, but, like Hulk, seems to prefer to punch. Something that can get both of them in trouble (he almost lost the gauntlet because he wanted to beat up people).

Comment: Fair, I think in that case though, he wasn't expecting Mantis or the other Guardians

Comment: Mmm, I think it was much closer to what Strange did with the apple, than with Dormammu.  The thing with Dormammu was a predefined reset (save point), while with the apple he actually turned back time.

Comment: Not just half of all sentient beings, half of all life period

Comment: @Valorum - There were surely a lot of trees in Wakanda, huh?

Comment: @Adamant - [Don't shoot the messenger](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/190910/20774)